# Auto insert Username/Password to batch files that request credentials

Tags: batch-file, passwords, credentials

2 bat files that contain the following

```
@echo off
set /p uname=Enter SQLPlus username: 
set /p pwd=Enter SQLPlus password:
```

I am trying to auto fill with credentials without changing the bat files.

I have been working with the following

Lets say I have an Update.bat and a Delete.Bat
both containing the following request before finishing the run

```
@echo off 
set /p uname=Enter SQLPlus username: 
set /p pwd=Enter SQLPlus password:
```

I was hoping I could create something similar to the following

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
set "username=test"
set "password=1234"
start "" "Update.bat"
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" "%username%{tab}%password%{enter}"
goto :EOF

@end

WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Once it is finished it moves on to the Delete.bat file and inserts credentials and finishes running bat file.

Comment: What does Unix have to do with any of this? Batch scripts only run on Windows hosts.

Comment: @SomethingDark So your saying you do not know the answer to my question, but you are capable of pointing out incorrect tags?

Comment: Trying to taunt me into giving you an answer isn't going to work.

Comment: @SomethingDark l will assume you do Not know/know off hand. To be clear I am not taunting, you trolled and avoided the question. So I gave my response. People who actually know answers do not respond first by pointing out classifications of a ticket.

Comment: @JohnDavis, I know the answer to your guestion. However I do not know the answer to the question posed by SomethingDark, and without you answering it to my satisfaction, I have no intention of divulging it. You are here for our help, so if you want that, you really should be prepared to work with us, instead of against us.

Comment: I'm not trolling; using incorrect tags is a surefire way to tell that the asker doesn't know how to properly convey their problem and they've almost certainly left something significant out of the question, which is going to result in followup work. PS: The answer to your problem is a one-liner that you would have found if you had searched for redirecting command input.

Comment: @SomethingDark Your saying TAG v.s User explanation of what they are trying to achieve, that TAGs hold more weight........Really? First let me validate this for your peace of mind. SomethingDark you are right I used UNIX TAG incorrectly. Unix and Batch do not go, Unix and Shell do. BUT knowing the answer and assuming that I knew what to search for is narcissistic. PS: Your response comes from a type of trauma, immediately needing to point out mistakes another individual made is typically associated with past experiences where you felt the same way. Instead of what you wanted which was help

Comment: yet you are associated with a website where people who are interested in learning or NEED HELP with coding, in order to point out flaws first instead of contributing to their knowledge and growth. I consider this the follow up work

Comment: Okay @JohnDavis, as you appear to have more interest in conflict, I will advise that you use the site search facility, and/or your web search engine of choice, to locate and test solutions using the method SomethingDark has graciously offered already, _(and which you've also seemingly ignored, or failed to perform 'the follow up work' on)_. BTW, it wasn't just the tag, your first word in your title was 'Unix' too.